# How symfony session worked backend?

Tags: php, session, symfony1, symfony-1.4, session-variables

I need to know how symfony session work in the backend.

- How can I change sessionId through symfony classes?
- How to change sessionId to write in the other user's session like change privilege to him/her without logout?

I know the classic way to do it with PHP but, I asked about symfony can handle this or no ?

**edit:**

addCredentials, removeCredential, remove privilege to the current user session, but I need to change another user session...

for example user x,y

from user x can I change session variables of user y with symfony classes

Comment: What the point to change session from a different user? What do you want to do?

Comment: for example: user's Privilege In session variable called "Ex:Role_id" I need user X to change the privilege of another user Y ... In the same time user Y see the changes on his sessions variables

Answer (score 1):

- to change sessionId use `sfSessionStorage::regenerate(true);`, this will regenerate the session id
- to change privilege, it depend on the authentication system you will use (maybe you will use the [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin)?). Symfony come with a basic [sfBasicSecurityUser object](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfBasicSecurityUser) witch provide the ability to change the privileges on the fly:

.

```
  // add $credential1 and $credential2 to current user
  $this->getUser()->addCredentials($credential1, $credential2);

  // remove credential $credential to current user
  $this->getUser()->removeCredential($credential);
```

Comment: addCredentials , removeCredential remove privilege to the current user session, but I need to change another user session... for example user x,y   from user x can I change session variables of user y with symfony classes